# UINavigationBar appearance not set when showing the view controller first time

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

With the following code you set the appearance of your UINavigationBar, but in my I case it is not set when the view controller shows for the first time. I just have to push another view controller and then it is set.

```
UIImage *gradientImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar44"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

UIImage *gradientImage32 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar32"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage32 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

Comment: Where are you doing this? You should be doing this in the app delegate if you need it on the first view.

Comment: Yeah, what @Rob said! Where are you putting this code?

Comment: u have to set this before presenting first view Controller..

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm calling `appearance` in the `-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions;` method before the first view controller is even instantiated... Must be another issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to set Uinavigationbar background image for ios 5 and above and ios less than ios 5

for ios 5 you can use the below code in app delegate

```
//Customize the look of the UINavBar for iOS5 devices
 UIImage *gradientImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar44"]   
 resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

UIImage *gradientImage32 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar32"]    
resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 
 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage32 
  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

but if you are using any ios version less than ios 5 you will have to subclass the UINavigationControl and overload drawRect like

```
@interface CustomNavigationBar : UINavigationBar
 @end

 @implementation CustomNavigationBar
 -(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
 {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myNavBarImage"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
 }
@end

// this can go anywhere
+(UINavigationController*) myCustomNavigationController
  {
   YOurViewController *vc = [[[YOurViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
   UINavigationController *nav = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
   loadNibNamed:@"CustomNavigationController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
   nav.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:vc];
   return nav;
 }
```

like this you can customize your navigation bar and will be valid for all the ios versions.

You can put a check for ios 5 by using

```
if ([[UINavigationBar class]respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {
   ///ios 5 and above.
 }
```